# Call outside variables within a function?

Tags: delphi, variables, global

I want to wrap the code of  Button1Click event handler into a function named Show() in order to reuse it later.

The event handler code:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  email := Form1.ed_Email.Text;
  password := Form1.Ed_typedpass.Text;

  MD5 := GetMD5;
  MD5.Init;
  MD5.Update(TByteDynArray(RawByteString(password)), Length(password));

  password := LowerCase(MD5.AsString);

end
```

When i put the code below into my script, i get non declared variables error ( as i am calling variables which are not declared inside my script ) but the reality isn't.

All variables work correctly inside procedures but not inside functions ?

```
function Show();
begin
  email := Form1.ed_Email.Text;
  password := Form1.Ed_typedpass.Text;

  MD5 := GetMD5;
  MD5.Init;
  MD5.Update(TByteDynArray(RawByteString(password)), Length(password));

  password := LowerCase(MD5.AsString);
end;
```

Comment: it would be helpful, if you provide us with location where the deceleration is done.Both the `global variables` and the `function`

Comment: Again, you need to read a basic manual on pascal syntax.  You're going no-where fast.  Variables have scope,which means, places that they are valid, and places that they are not valid.   `TSomething.MyClickyProcedure` is a procedure that belongs to a class, and can access the fields in that class.  A Function `Show` without a `TSomething.` in it, can not access them.

Comment: -1 for repeatedly asking lazy questions.

Answer (score 5):

It would appear that you are trying to use global variables, or member variables, throughout your code where local variables should be used. Don't do that. It's an bad practice that will give you enormous amounts of pain in the future. Lose that bad habit before you write too much code the wrong way.

Always use local variables where it is possible to do so.

```
procedure Show;
var
  email: string;
  password: string;
  MD5: TMD5;
begin
  email := Form1.ed_Email.Text;
  password := Form1.Ed_typedpass.Text;

  MD5 := GetMD5;
  MD5.Init;
  MD5.Update(TByteDynArray(RawByteString(password)), Length(password));
  password := LowerCase(MD5.AsString);
end;
```

I had to guess at the type of `MD5` but you can substitute this with the actual type.

If you do need to use members then either pass them to the method as a parameter, or make the procedure a method of the form class that owns the members.

It seems likely that these variables are members of `TForm2` and if you really need them to be members of `TForm2` then you probably should make `Show` a `TForm2` method. That said, `Show` is a bad choice of name since it is already a method of `TForm`.

---

I also guessed at the type for `password` but perhaps it needs to be `AnsiString` judging from the type-casting that goes on in the `MD5.Update` call. Or, perhaps `Length` should be `ByteLength`. In other words, I suspect that you have a bug in the `MD5.Update` line which will reveal itself once you get the code to compile.

Comment: The code you gave me is already working, the second code which i've added which cause me the problem. '_' Thanks for reply

Comment: @RafikBari Your question would be easier to answer if you could state where `email`, `password` and `MD5` are defined. I am quite sure that they are declared in the wrong place at the moment but at the moment I can only guess at what you have got wrong.

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph alone. Another one for the suggestion to use parameters (if SO would let me)

Answer (score 1):

`Function` in `Delphi` cannot be without a return type.
Try making it into a `Procedure`.
Also you have not mentioned the base class for the function deceleration.
Try this

```
Procedure TForm1.Show();//TForm2 based on your decelaration
begin

 email := Form1.ed_Email.Text;
 password := Form1.Ed_typedpass.Text;

 MD5 := GetMD5;
 MD5.Init;
 MD5.Update(TByteDynArray(RawByteString(password)), Length(password));
 password := LowerCase(MD5.AsString);
end;
```

Comment: This answer has some problems. If this is the answer then making the code be a method of `TForm1` brings `email` and `password` into scope. That's fine, but you don't want to write `Form1.`. You should instead use `Self.` which can of course be omitted.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes,but he has not mentioned where the function is placed.And he has got 2 forms Form1 and Form2.But definitely u cannot have it as a function.

Comment: @David Heffernan: If the broken code is fixed later, the comment will be out of sync. What to do in that case?

Comment: I know the question is missing a lot. I'm trying to help. If you are going to guess at `TForm1` as the owner of `email`, `password` etc. then you should remove `Form1.` but on the other hand if it works as a `TForm2` method then it's more likely that these members are `TForm2` members. But we are having to guess!